# Tornado crashed with assert error

Tags: tornado

According to official doc http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html, I'm using async feature of tornado like this:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    ...
    response = yield calendar.events()
    self.write(json.dumps(response, default=json_util.default))
    self.finish()
```

`calendar.events()` is database operation, it crashed with below assert error, is there anything wrong?

```
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='xxxx:9999', method='GET', uri='/event_list?calendar_guid=6', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='xxxx', headers={'Host': 'xxxx:9999', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (apple-x86_64-darwin14.4.0) Siege/3.1.0', 'Connection': 'close', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1369, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1572, in wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 242, in wrapper
    Runner(result, future, yielded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 817, in __init__
    if self.handle_yield(first_yielded):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 956, in handle_yield
    self.future = convert_yielded(yielded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1022, in convert_yielded
    return multi_future(yielded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 643, in multi_future
    assert all(is_future(i) for i in children)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1):

To be used with the `yield` statement in a Tornado coroutine, a method must be specifically written for this purpose. Looks like the `calendar.events` method you call does not return a Tornado `Future` object, so I infer it's not designed for use as a non-blocking method within a Tornado coroutine.

You can call it without the `yield` keyword, but you'll have to accept that you're blocking the event loop while `events` executes. Alternatively, use a ThreadPoolExecutor. Tornado's maintainer Ben Darnell has a nice example of this here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-tornado/35BiBKdSCNw/zx561l-sABIJ

If `calendar` is a MySQLdb object, try:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.process import cpu_count

# global threadpool
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count())

class Handler(RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        response = yield pool.submit(calendar.events)
        self.write(json.dumps(response, default=json_util.default))
```

Final notes: with `gen.coroutine`, the `asynchronous` decorator is not needed, nor is `self.finish`.

Comment: its mysqldb I'm using. so according to this example, my code should be `response = yield pool.submit(calendar.events)`  right?

Comment: BTW, do you know where I can find a nice tutorial about how to implement async tornado handler based on mysqldb

Comment: I've edited my answer. No I don't know of a MySQL / Tornado tutorial, sorry.